# Is it possible to cancel "keyword argument repeated" exception in python 2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.6

The code runs on python 2.5 but fails with this exception on 2.6

Comment: I would assume it's a parse-time error, so no. Code doing this is broken anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That exception is a syntax error in the source, and the only way to fix it is to correct the function call.

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 14:53:14)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(x): pass
...
>>> f(x=1, x=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
>>> f(x=1, **{'x': 2})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(x): pass
...
>>> f(x=1, x=2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
>>> f(x=2, **{'x': 1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
```